# Add Min Value on Query Output in Separate Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
No    Item     Value   
----------------------------
1     A        5
2     B        8
3     C        9
```

If I use Min function on `Value` field, then I'll get `5`.

My question is, how can I put the MIN value into a new column? Like the following result:

```
No    Item     Value   newCol
----------------------------
1     A        5       5
2     B        8       5
3     C        9       5
```

Is it possible to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to persist this data in your table (in which case you'll need a computed column)? Or are you trying to just use this minimum value in a query (in which the given answer will do that for you)?

Comment: @RichBenner, well . Just a query is enough. But I have an error .. 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. this is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, blah blah blah'

Comment: it shouldn't do because of the min(value) field. I've given another answer, check it out to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to do the subquery in a join, you'll have to name the field. Something like this;

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (No int, item nvarchar(1), value int)
INSERT INTO #TestData (No, item, value)
VALUES
(1,'A',5)
,(2,'B',8)
,(3,'C',9)
```

Query

```
SELECT 
     td.No
    ,td.item
    ,td.value
    ,a.Min_Value
FROM #TestData td
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT
       MIN(Value) Min_Value
    FROM #TestData
) a
```

Result

```
No  item    value   Min_Value
1   A       5       5
2   B       8       5
3   C       9       5
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
select No, Item, Value, (select min(value) from table)
from table
```

should do it.

Comment: Was writing something similar, but was wondering if @Haminteu was referring to an actual inserting the minimum value for some reason into a new column in the db. Setting up a View to handle this requirement might seem a better option maybe?

Comment: Read the question before answering. The question is about inserting a value not selecting a result set.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny, are you sure? A result-set column is a column too.

Comment: @jarlh And where exactly have I said it isn't? But I hope you realize this is not going to magically insert into a new column.

Comment: The answer should include the `insert into new Column` part too.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny OP has confirmed that a query is fine, it doesn't need to be persisted in the table.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny, do you mean a base table column? The value will be not very magically inserted into a result-set column!

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny why not supply your own answer if you disagree with the one given?

Comment: @jarlh ***"My question is, how can I put the MIN value into a new column?"*** You are either inserting this value in a column in a new table or updating a column in an existing table. The answer does not contain this part which is the very question asked by OP.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny and you realise that asking questions to clarify the question is perfectly acceptable? People come here because they're unsure how to do what they want. Being pedantic with terminology for inexperienced users isn't the way of helping.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that even simpler by using an appropriate `OVER()` clause.

```
SELECT *
   , MIN(Value) OVER () AS [newCol]
FROM Table
```

This would be simpler and less resource consuming than a `(SELECT MIN(Value) FROM TABLE)` in the top level `SELECT`.

Sample code:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (No int, Item char(1), Value int)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1, 'A', 5), (2, 'B', 8), (3, 'C', 9)

SELECT *
    , MIN(Value) OVER () AS [newCol]
FROM @tbl
```

Comment: @RichBenner The power of windowed functions. There was a cool video on this, somewhere. I'll try to find it and post a comment here, if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: yeah, that would be great if you wouldn't mind. I've used windowing functions a lot but there's always something new to learn :)

Comment: @RichBenner Adam Machanic always has great content. Hope you find [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YK-ufNpMeLU) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using cross join with min value from table :
`SELECT * FROM #Tbl1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(Value1) Value1 FROM #Tbl1) A`